# Where is the second part of the Fighter's guild questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

(For Aldmeri Dominion)

I just finished the first "chunk" of quests at Buraniim Isle in Auridon and I can't find where the journey continues. The guildmaster said that she'll "see me down the riverline" but I don't know where that would be.

Edit:
Letting everyone know that, even though I am level 43, the fighter's guild "runner" came to meet me in Reaper's March anyways, to continue the questline. Just took time and eventually she just showed up. I wonder if this will happen now that I'm in coldharbor though...

Edit2: It actually did happen in Coldharbor, and also in the first veteran zone. I've now completed the FG questline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got two misunderstandings which lead to your question or "problem":

- First of all, the storylines in ESO aren't just "quest follows quest till you're done". They're offered at intervalls. This includes the **main quest**, the **fighters guild** and the **mages guild** so far. You'll typically be notified by some kind of missive or similar dialog that a new quest/step is available to you. These aren't missable, so you don't have to worry about them.

  - **Main Story:** In the beginning, the *Prophet* will appear before you once you pass specific locations in towns, for example some gate or bridge. He'll appear and attempt to talk to you. Later on you'll be invited by other means, e.g. by a *banekin*, but the overall concept stays the same. You can't miss him. Even if you just ran past him, you'll still get the quest added to your quest journal.
  - **Fighters Guild:** *Bera Moorsmith* will approach and follow you for a short time if you've got a new quest waiting for you and you approach any Fighters Guild hall in one of the bigger cities. She'll send you to the proper guild hall to continue.
  - **Mages Guild:** Similar to the *Prophet* some mage (spoiler) will appear once you pass specific landmarks or positions. He'll greet you and tell you to go to some specific guild hall.
- And second, you're misunderstanding your Argonian friend. Argonians have a **quite limited vocabulary** due to their origins etc. Without elaborating too much about this, it's pretty easy to notice - especially while playing in the *Ebonheart Pact*. This is most likely due to their isolation in *Black Marsh*. Some might know more words in Cyrodiilic (the language your character perceives as English, German, or French), but that's different from Argonian to Argonian.

  For example, the Argonians lack a variety of names for bodies of water. Due to this they'll generally refer to water as *river*. The ocean is just a very big river and a puddle or pond is just a very small one.

  In a similar way, Argonians lack a specific word for *time*. This time they use use a metaphor since they don't have any similar word, in your case *"further down the river"*. While this might refer to some place further down some river, it's typically their interpretation of *"in the (near) future"*. Imagine some Argonian seeing something (or themselves being) in a river. In the future, they'll be further down the river, explaining this concept/association.

Comment: nothing but <3 for you mars. thank you. I realize now that they will come to me later. I forgot that the argonian also said "we'll come get you when we've decoded the scroll" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

For every alliance, if you joined the Mages Guild or the Fighters Guild, you will be notified when a new quest is available for your level.

This is done via a messenger (Named Bera Moorsmith for the Ebonheart Pact, but I imagine it's the same for the other alliances as well).

According to [Esohead](http://esohead.com/quests#type:3) you start the chain at level 5 and then you continue to receive new quests at levels 8, 15, 25, 33 and 43 (Esohead lists a level 50 Mages Guild quest, but no level 50 Fighters Guild quest).

So, just be on your merry way until Bera runs up to you!

Comment: good to know. I went all the way back to start the questline. I'm at level 43 so I hope they show up sooner than later :3